# If clause does not give update only works insertion. Why update is not working?

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to update and insert conditionally but query always goes "Insert" data. No "update" anyway. My code is below:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <label>ID: </label> <input type="text" name="id">
    <label>Subject: </label> <input type="text" name="subject">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php 
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "zidm"); 

$id=$_POST['id'];
$subject=$_POST['subject'];


if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
      $sql = "UPDATE exam  SET subject = '$subject'  WHERE id = '$id'";    
    mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    echo "Data Updated";
  }
  else {
 $sql="INSERT INTO exam (subject) VALUES ( '$subject)";
    mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    echo "Data Inserted";
  }

  ?>
```

Comment: You have the `else` which will always fire on page load. Try wrapping the entire `update`/`insert` logic in form submission check.

Comment: It looks like it should work (other than the syntax error in your insert statement). Try `var_dump($_POST);` to make sure the submit variable exists. Though why are you inserting blank values if the form isn't submitted?

Comment: (1) use prepared statements if you did things like forgetting to close the single quote after the `'$subject` on the insert, would not occur anymore (2) your code attempts to insert even if there is nothing posted.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are checking for form submission but also have an `else` statement which will always fire on page load. You need to wrap your entire logic in the form submission check and then check for the `id` parameter.

```
// Form was submitted
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if (!empty($_POST['id'])) {
        // Update
    } else {
        // Insert
    }
}
```